# Clipping raster file using shapefile that has different blocks inside?

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, clip

I have a TIFF file as shown below:

[image]

I have a shapefile as shown:

[image]

How can I separate the TIFF file into different blocks using the above shapefile?

Comment: Select a county, clip by the selection. Select the next county, clip by that selection, etc, pp.

Comment: can I select all counties and clip at one shot?

Comment: Then you will clip all counties at once - into one file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Clip Raster by Mask` tool from the Toolbox and click on the green iterator to clip the raster image by each smaller boundary inside the shapefile:

[image]

Input Raster:

[image]

Using the above tool with iterator enabled, here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried this and an error pops up. ERROR 4: `C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_e43b7fe9c62040ceb676af2e73b6b99c/29aa50107e1345f1a3df09cdeda4ca39/MASK.shp' not recognized as a supported file format.

Comment: Got it working. Saved it as a permanent file rather than temporary!

Comment: Can you tell me how to save these different files with their id?

Comment: I want to save these different tiffs generated with the 'id's of block. Can I do that?

Comment: Based on your newly posted question, I don't think it is possible without coding (programming).

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your efforts